# Wordpress cookie for only one time

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

i'm struggling with a cookie matter for the past 2 hours. What i'm trying to do is to set a cookie with Javascript with a click event on a link and then let the default redirection to be happened. In the new page a want to perform an operation because of the cookies value and then delete it, so on a possible reload the site works normal again.
The cookie will be a switch in order to determine if i'm going to run a pre_get_post function on my archive. The problem is that i cant find how to delete the cookie after i've grabbed it's value.
Here is my code

```
function modify_query( $query ) {
    $cookie_data = $GLOBALS['cookie_data'];
    if (  $query->is_main_query() && isset( $cookie_data )) {
        $meta_query = array(
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key'   => 'key',
                    'value' => $cookie_data,
                )
            )
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    } // end if
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_query' );



function get_cookie() {
        if(isset($_COOKIE['test_data'])){
            global $cookie_data;
            $cookie_data = $_COOKIE['cookie_data'];
            unset( $_COOKIE['cookie_data'] );
            setcookie( 'cookie_data', '', time()-3600, '/');
        }
    }
    add_action('init', 'get_cookie', 90);
```

Comment: Where & how are you setting the cookie? (*You also need to remember that the cookie won't be removed until the next page load.*)

Comment: The cookie is set on product page, and then when i navigate to archive i want to read the cookie and then delete it, the problem is that the $cookie_data is empty after i unset and remove the cookie

Comment: As i see it , the  setcookie( 'cookie_data', '', time()-3600, '/'); in the get_cookie() function deletes the cookie before it can it stored in the global variable , although it's later in excecution time. I don't know i'm confused